# Mainframe problems, due to internet drops

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

Apologies at forehand, for the amound of information, but I tried to be as thorough as possible. If any information is still needed, please let me know.

Background:

I am a junior mainframe programmer, who started out a few months ago with learning the mainframe. I know my way around pretty well, when it comes to jcl, cobol etc, but when it comes to maintenance of the mainframe, I'm not all that familiar.

I'm currently following a course, using the mainframe of the institution (which is an emualtor, not a real one). Sadly my teacher is still learning how to maintaine a mainframe, so he doesn't really know either. So calling the tech department is not an option. 
Basically I am hoping that someone here, heared of the problem before. I don't know where to look. If the problem is in my wifi connection, or if it is with the mainframe. Seems to go both ways.

Specifications:

- My OS:               Windows 7
- Laptop: HP Elitebook, with dualboot Windows7 and Linux
- Mainframe emulator:  Tom Brennan's Vista TN3270, Z/OS
                   Just in case I added my Vista.ini below
- Connection:          through external ip adres

N.B. I have reinstalled wifi drivers, this didn't do anything.

Problem:

The mainframe workt properly up until 2 weeks ago, when my provider performed some maintenance on the internet in my neighbourhood. Since then, I am experiencing internet drops. They happen every +- 5sec and last (as far as I can tell) around 20-30 ms (both on wifi and cable).

It is not long enough for the browser and other applications to notice. Even my windows doesn't notice the drop. My mainframe connection however does notice the drop. My connection with the mainframe is not lost completely. The screen stays open and visible, but pressing any button does nothing. I then have to close vista, reopen, loggin again and then it works fine. Till 5 minutes later, when it starts over again.

Last night I pinged the IP and at the same time, pinged google, in order to figure out if it whas only the mainframe connection with a problem, or not. The ping did fine for minutes on end, until I started Vista after a few minutes and then both pings crashed instantly, couldn't send or receive any packages anymore.

Extra info:

- I called my provider and they send a tech guy, they say there is nothing wrong with my internet connection.
- Connecting to the external IP adres, from another wifi connection gives me no problems. It only goes wrong from my home addres / wifi.
- Other people on the same mainframe have no problems, no mather where they are.
- There is another mainframe I can reach and that one does not seem to have any problems what so ever.
- Other ssh / external connections to other IP adresses don't give me any problems.
- I tried testing it on Linux and other computers, but without having Vista to try, i don't now how else to test the problem. Since browser and other applications have no problems.
- I get no message what so ever when the mainframe connections stops.
- I looked at a number of logfiles on the mainframe, but basically I don't know which ones I need to find a possible clue or answer.

If someone knows anything, even just to send me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated. Having to reconnect every 5 minutes is starting to be really annoying and keeps me from my studies/work.

[Vista]

LastSession=standard.ses

Hostnames=

IPnames=

Portnums=3270,23

TN3270E=1,1

SSL=0,0

Lunames=,

KeepAliveTime=60

Comment: this really shouldn't be tagged with mainframe as it has nothing to do with the mainframe. The issue is with your connection. When the emulator losses connection to the terminal, that happens. It could be an issue with your VPN or you companies firewall, but it doesn't sound anything wrong with the mainframe

Comment: Thx you. I wasn't sure wheter to put it here or not. It doesn't sound like a problem with the mainframe / connection, but as I said, I am not al that familiar, so wanted to be sure. 

I am not using a VPN, but i'll be sure to check out the firewall!